# How do i generate random function in python 3?

Tags: python

Im new to python and im trying to figure out how can i generate random function.
Im trying this code but it gives me error.
can someone help me?`

```
import random

def Ai1(self):
    self.name = 'Goblin'
def Ai2(self):
    self.name = 'Orc'

enemy = random.choice[(Ai1,Ai2)]
enemy.name()
```

`

Comment: Did you try Googling "python random" to arrive at [the documentation for `random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)?

Comment: `random.choice()` is a function, not a list. Call it don't try to index it - `random.choice([Ali1,Ali2])` also, you cannot do `enemy.name()` , Ali1 is a function, you have to do `enemy()` , maybe you can write the rest of the logic inside the function.

Comment: @Anand S Kumar - Can u give me an example ? to be honest im confuse.

Comment: There are many examples in the documentation for `random`, linked above.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 ow thanks

Answer (score 0):

One problem that you are having with your code is that the functions are not defined inside of a class, thus you cannot have:

```
    Ai1(self):
        self.name = 'Goblin'
```

if this is something you want to do first you need to define a class

```
    class enemies:
        Ai1(self):
            self.name = 'Goblin'
```

Secondly I personally think it would be easier to use a list of enemies something like:

```
    enemies = ['Goblin', 'Orc']

    rand = random.randint(0,1)
    enemy = enemies[rand]
    print(enemy)
```

If your list is larger than 2 you would have to increase the 1 to len(enemies) -1

Comment: Why `rand = random.randint(0,1); enemy = enemies[rand]` rather than `enemy = random.choice(enemies)`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I am just a guy who likes numbers, your way is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's pretty simple

you tried to def a str function but you need to make a list

```
import random
mylist = ['Orc','Goblin']
enemy = random.choice(mylist)#it randomly choose a value in a list
print(enemy)
```

you can also use class

```
import random
class self:
    def name():
        mylist = ['Orc','Goblin']
        enemy = random.choice(mylist)
        print(enemy)
self.name()
```

but the simplest mode is the ninja method

```
import random
print(random.choice(['Orc','Goblin']))
```

that's it.

hope it helped you!